# Change Bearer-Token-Type in Spring Cloud OAuth

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, gitlab, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

I'm using Spring Cloud OAuth, I'm using the official sample from https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sso/ with GitLab (https://about.gitlab.com/) as OAuth Provider.

The Problem is that GitLab sends a Token of the Type "bearer" and Spring Cloud SSO retrieves the token and sends a Header in the form of
`Authorization bearer xxxxxxx`
which is rejected by the GitLab Server cause according to the documentation it only accepts Tokens in the form of
`Authorization Bearer xxxxxxx`.

This is probably a bug in the GitLab Server but is there any way to work around this problem with Spring Cloud SSO.

**Update 19.03.:**

This is what I've tried in SsoApplication.java of the SpringCloud-sample.

```
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    private void modifyOAuthRestTemplate() {
        this.oAuth2RestTemplate.setAuthenticator(new OAuth2RequestAuthenticator() { // this line gets called
            @Override
            public void authenticate(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, OAuth2ClientContext clientContext, ClientHttpRequest request) {
                // this line is never called
            }
        });
    }
```

instead of the newly Injected OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails the "original" one gets called. Everytime I try to authenticate in the sample app

Comment: Isn't gitlab the same as github (which I know works)?

Comment: GitLab is a Ruby-Based GitLab clone. But it does not run on the same codebase as GitHub. (GitHub also works for me)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: there is a callback in Spring Cloud if you define a bean of type `UserInfoRestTemplateCustomizer` you will get an instance of `OAuth2RestTemplate` during startup where you can apply customizations (e.g. an `OAuth2RequestAuthenticator` to change "Bearer" to "bearer").

The workaround I have seen others use is to `@Autowired` the `OAuth2RestTemplate` and modify its `OAuth2RequestAuthenticator` in a `@PostConstruct` (before it is used anyway).

Comment: I tried that, but the @Autowired OAuth2RestTemplate is not the same as the one used during authentication.

Comment: Define "during authentication". There is a `@Primary` `OAuth2RestTemplate` by default so it has to be the same as the one in the authentication processing filter. I'm not sure what you are saying really.